# Calculus limit epsilon delta

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove using only the epsilon , delta - definition

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 2}\dfrac{1}{x} = 0.5$

Given $\epsilon > 0 $, there exists a delta such that

$ 0<|x-2|< \delta$  implies $|(1/x) – 0.5| < \epsilon$.

Therefore, $$\begin{align}|(1/x) – 0.5| & = |(2-x)/2x| \\ 
& =|\frac{-(x-2)}{2(x-2+2)}| \\ & < |\frac{(x-2)}{2(x-2)} |=\frac{|x-2|}{2|x-2|}=\delta/2\delta=0.5
\end{align}$$

But epsilon is $> 0$. My $0.5$ is causing issue.

Comment: You made an arithmetic error: $A > 0$ and $|x-2| < \delta$ implies $A / |x-2| > A/\delta$, not $A/|x-2| < A/\delta$. (this error is not the only thing you're missing for solving the problem -- you need to find another way to deal with the denominator to ensure it stays away from zero)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: You want the following to hold for all $x$ such that $2-\delta < x < 2+\delta$:

$\left|\dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{2}\right| < \epsilon$

$-\epsilon < \dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{2} < \epsilon$

$\dfrac{1}{2} -\epsilon < \dfrac{1}{x}< \dfrac{1}{2} + \epsilon$

For what range of values for $x$ is this inequality true? That will help you pick $\delta$.

Comment: So i say |x-2|<0 so -2<x<2 such that     |(1/x)-0.5| < epsilon by picking delta to be 0?

Comment: No, you cannot pick $\delta = 0$, since the $\epsilon$,$\delta$ definition requires $\delta > 0$. Did you try to solve $\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon < \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{2}+\epsilon$ for $x$?

Comment: @TBX $\delta=0$ is not an option. But assuming the three numbers in the last displayed equation are positive, one can take the reciprocals of all three and reverse the order.

Comment: this is what i did i edited the solution

Answer (score 1):

This is the jist of it. You are **required** to bound the value of $ | \dfrac 1 x - \dfrac 1 2 |  $. But you are only **allowed** to bound $ |x  - 2| $. So by **putting in** a restriction on $ |x - 2| \lt \delta$ you need to **achieve** the  restriction $ | \dfrac 1 x - \dfrac 1 2  | \lt \epsilon$. And more importantly you need to prove that such a $\delta$ exists for every $\epsilon \gt 0$. So we begin with $ |f(x) - L| $.

$$  | \dfrac 1 x - \dfrac 1 2 | = \frac{|x - 2|}{2|x|} ---(1)  $$

Since we can bound $|x - 2|$ as *severely* as we want we may as well allow $$ |x - 2| \lt 1 \iff x \in ( 1, 3 ) \implies |x| \gt 1  \implies \frac{1}{|x|} \lt 1 $$

Using this on $(1)$ we have,

$$ | \dfrac 1 x - \dfrac 1 2  | \lt \dfrac{|x - 2|}{2} \;\; \text{as long as } |x - 2| \lt 1 $$

Now we have a bound on $  | \dfrac 1 x - \dfrac 1 2  |  $ which is a multiple of $ |x - 2| $. So as soon as we restrict $ |x - 2| $ we automatically restrict $ | \dfrac 1 x - \dfrac 1 2  |  $.

All we need to do is to choose $ \delta = 2 \epsilon $ and we will be done.

But not so fast. we used the additional assumption that $ |x - 2| \lt 1$. So if we let $ \delta = \min \{2 \epsilon, 1\} $ then all our required constraints will be satisfied.

The most important thing to notice is that such a $\delta \;$ ***exists*** for any $\epsilon \gt 0$.

Comment: My school taught me the method i used. Why cant i use my method in this question?

Comment: For starters it is not valid to claim $$  \dfrac{A}{ |2(x - 2 + 2)| } \lt \dfrac{A}{ |2(x - 2 )| } $$.Suppose $x = \frac 1 2$??And you've gotten nowhere near proving the requirement that I have tried to explain in my answer. And I am doubtful you learnt the statement $ \forall \epsilon \gt 0 \; \exists \delta \gt 0 $ such that $ |x - 2| \lt \delta \implies | \dfrac 1 x - \dfrac 1 2 | \lt \epsilon$ in school