# Proving a limit with epsilon delta definition: $\lim\limits_{x\to 3} \frac{2}{x+1} =\frac12$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I am in honors Calculus I and my teacher is really stressing this limit proof. I understand the examples she goes over in class but she gave us a problem for home work and i just don't know how to start it. I appreciate any help!

$$\lim_{x\to 3}  \frac{2}{x+1} =\frac12$$

Comment: That is supposed to say lim as x approaches 3

Comment: Isn't there any example that looks familiar? How about obtaining an expression for $\frac{2}{x+1} - \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Its how my teacher gave it to us. It just means the limit value is 3. Heres the step im stuck at:

f(x)=L+- ε
2=(1/2+-ε)x + 1
x= 3+- 2/ε

I think i have to define values for x(0) and x(1)

Comment: check this out:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65667/how-to-prove-a-limit-exists-using-the-epsilon-delta-definition-of-a-limit?rq=1

Comment: You also might find this helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930576/calculus-limit-epsilon-delta

Comment: I just really need help setting it up for this kind of problem.

Comment: The last link you sent me was the last example i did in class. I fully understand how it works but when ever i get a new problem i just dont get how to start it. I created values for  delta (o) and delta (1).I got Delta (0) equals 2/ε and for delta (1) i got -2/ε. However, i think that is incorrect.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "f(x)=L+- ε 2=(1/2+-ε)x + 1 x= 3+- 2/ε". can you state in your post using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ notation what you have to prove?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

To get started, you need to work with the inequality $\displaystyle\left|\frac{2}{x+1}-\frac{1}{2}\right|<\epsilon$.  We can rewrite this as $\displaystyle\left|\frac{4-(x+1)}{2(x+1)}\right|<\epsilon$, which gives $\displaystyle\left|\frac{3-x}{2(x+1)}\right|<\epsilon$ or, equivalently, $\displaystyle\frac{\left|x-3\right|}{2|x+1|}<\epsilon$.

Now we need to get an upper bound for the factor $\frac{1}{|x+1|}$, so one way to do this is to assume

that our value of $\delta \le 1$.  Under this assumption,

$0<|x-3|<\delta\implies|x-3|<1\implies 2<x<4\implies3<x+1<5\implies$

$\;\;\;\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}>\frac{1}{x+1}>\frac{1}{5}\implies \frac{1}{\left|x+1\right|}<\frac{1}{3}$.

---

Now you need to find a $\delta>0$ which satisfies $\delta\le1$,  and

$\displaystyle0<|x-3|<\delta\implies\frac{|x-3|}{2|x+1|}=\frac{|x-3|}{2}\frac{1}{|x+1|}<\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!!

Comment: You're welcome.  (The actual proof would start something like this:  Let $\epsilon>0$ be given, and let $\delta=\cdots$.)

Answer (score 0):

Given $ \delta \gt 0 $ such that $|x-3|\lt \delta, x\in(3-\delta,3+\delta)\subset[2,4]$,  $$ |\dfrac{2}{x+1} -\dfrac12 |=|\dfrac{3-x}{2(x+1)}|\lt \dfrac{\delta}{2|x+1|}\lt \dfrac{\delta}{8}:= \varepsilon$$.

Hence, $ \forall \varepsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta \gt 0 $ such that $|x-3|\lt \delta$ implies  $ |\dfrac{2}{x+1} -\dfrac12 | \lt \varepsilon$. By definition, $\lim_{x\to 3}  \dfrac{2}{x+1} =\dfrac12$. This proof also shows the given function is uniformly continuous at x=3.